# Using a Normal Distribution to motivate the use of a Parameter Penalty in Negative Log-Likelihood

Tags: likelihood

This is a question arose from an argument I had about a statistical explanation.

We are comparing two models using their negative log-likelihoods. Given that we are unable to split the data into a training and test set (why is not important in this question), we have to find another way to account for the complexity of the models, i.e., we want to penalize models with more parameters. We do this by adding 3 * NumberOfParameters to the negative log-likelihood of each model. We call this the 'error'. The model with the lowest error gets chosen.

---

**Here is the explanation that I was given for this (the one that I disagree with):**

1. Consider a standard normal distribution with a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1.
2. By evaluating the probability density function (pdf) of this distribution at two specific values, 0 and 2.45, I find that they are 0.39894 and 0.019837. I calculate the difference in the logarithms of these pdf values: $\ln(0.39894) - \ln(0.019837) = 3$.
3. As 2.45 standard deviations corresponds to a 98% confidence interval, I conclude that if the difference in the negative log-likelihoods of two models (with one model having 1 more parameter than the other) is greater than 3, it indicates a significant difference between the models, falling outside the 98% confidence interval.

---

I don't understand the above. Here are my objections which depend on the interpretation of the aforementioned explanation.

**Interpretation 1**: The explanation assumes that likelihoods follow a normal distribution, and our taks is to build a confidence interval around one and check whether the other one is in it, then

1. This does not make sense. Likelihoods don't follow a distribution.
2. Even if they did, using the above explanation means that we must find the 'pdf' of two likelihoods in order to compare them.

**Interpretation 2**: The explanation assumes that likelihoods themselves can be treated like probability densities of some normal variable, where one value is the pdf at the mean.

1. Again, this does not make sense, likelihoods are definitely not probabilities (this is Stats 101!).
2. Even if they were probabilities, how can we assume that they are pdf values of some normal distribution? How can we assume that they are both from the same distribution? How can we assume that the larger value corresponds to the pdf of the mean of that distribution? Doesn't make any sense to me.

---

Before anybody mentions it, I am familiar with the AIC (I know that under certain conditions we can use a parameter penalty to compare log-likelihoods), but I'm mostly interested in the validity of the argument above for using a parameter penalty of 3.

My question is here mostly out of desperation. I have thought and argued about this, but the other person who is arguing in favor of the above 'explanation' is quite adamant that it is correct. I would really appreciate if somebody knowledgeable could point us in the right direction and clear any confusion/mistakes that I (or the other individual) may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion here stemmed from the fact that the other person was confused about the meaning of a likelihood. He was under the impression that it was a probability of some random variable. This means the 'explanation' above is incorrect.